# Windows server 2008R2 sql error 10025

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, networking, firewall

I am having problems with network connectivity between ms server 2008R2/sql server 2008 and msserver 2003/sql server 2005: every time I try to open a connection with sql management studio or sqlcmd I get a long timeout and then an sql error 10052: remote computer closed connection unexpectedly.

Also, there is a hardware firewall between them, which permits only 1433 tcp traffic.

I've tested some other combinations:

win 2008R2/sql 2008 ---> firewall ---> win2003 sql2005 ( sql error 10025)

win 2008R2/sql 2005 ---> firewall ---> win 2003 sql2005 (sql error 10025)

win 2008R2/sql 2008 ---> win2003 sql2005 (oK!)

win7 X86/sql 2008  ---> firewall ---> win 2003 sql2005 ( ok!!!)

win7 X86/sql 2005  ---> firewall ---> win 2003 sql2005 ( ok!!!)

win 2003/sql 2005 ---> firewall ---> win 2003 sql2005 (ok!)

So it seams that the real issue lies in combined behavior of win2008R2 and firewall. What could have changed so drasticly between win 2003, win7 and win2008R2? Maybe I need some additional roules on the firewall? Tcpdump shows packets travelling both directions.

Disabling firewall is not an option because I am working on our client's site, which has tough security protocols.

Answer (score 0):

Smells more a windows network configuration problem not directly related to the MS SQL Server.
I can try a shot at disabling SNP at that 2008 server.

Try reading this article

[A transport-level error" message when an application connects to SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942861?ln=en-us)